# How does a daemon work when a computer installed linux or unix start and shutdown

Tags: daemon

How to start and close a daemon when start and shutdown a computer?
I just want to learn how to  write a daemon process.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link is a good document you can follow in this purpose. This describes how to write a `UNIX` daemon.

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/22234881/How-To-Write-a-UNIX-Daemon